# Implementing a flash message on a Smarty site?

Tags: php, session, smarty, flash-message

I'm trying to implement a "Flash Message" (a little message that'll show on the top on the "next" request, saying things like "record saved"), in a PHP site that has pretty messy code and uses Smarty.

The best I could come up with is:

1. I set the message in a specially named variable in $_SESSION
2. My "header" template checks for that variable ($smarty.session.flash) and if it's set, it shows the message
3. After rendering, and only if a template was rendered, clear the $_SESSION variable.

My problem is with #3. The only way I could find of doing it was registering an output filter with Smarty:

```
function smarty_outputfilter_flashmessage($tpl_output, $smarty) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['flash'])) {
        $_SESSION['flash'] = "";
    }
    return $tpl_output;
}

$smarty->register_outputfilter("smarty_outputfilter_flashmessage");
```

The problem with that is that, if a template has sub-templates, that function gets called for each sub-template. Also, there are a number of places in the code that do

```
$variable = $smarty->fetch('something.tpl')
```

which also triggers my outputfilter.

When that happens, the output filter clears the session variable before the header template is rendered, and the message is lost.

Any ideas/suggestions on how to better do this?

Is there some kind of PHP built-in callback to execute a custom function when a request "ends"? (With that, I could add the clearing there, and have the output_filter simply set a variable to show whether *something* was rendered)

Ideally, something that gets called unless the code calls die()?

Or, of course, another completely different and better way to do this?

Thanks!
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seriously used PHP or Smarty in ages, but instead of trying to guess when a template was rendered, can't you do a Smarty function that does something like:

```
function smarty_function_pop_flash_message($params, $smarty) {
    $msg = "";
    if (isset($_SESSION['flash'])) {
        $msg = $_SESSION['flash'];
        $_SESSION['flash'] = "";
    }
    return $msg;
}
```

And then in the template where you show this message:

```
{if isset($smarty.session.flash) && $smarty.session.flash != ''}
    <div id="flash">{pop_flash_message}</div>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I have used Smarty in the past, and wanted to be able to show messages, I have used the following method.

Within the PHP Script which processes the action and then generates the message:

```
$_SESSION['message'][] = 'The Message Content!';
```

Within the PHP Script which processes the next request/page and invokes the Smarty Template:

```
$smarty->assign( 'messages' , $_SESSION['message'] );
unset( $_SESSION['messages'] );
```

Within the Smarty Template (normally a commonly reused one, like the Header section

```
{include file='messages.tpl'}
```

And then within the "messages.tpl" Smarty template

```
{if $messages}
  <div id="messages">
    <ul>
      {foreach $messages as $m}
        <li>{$m}</li>
      {/foreach}
    </ul>
  </div>
{/if}
```

It is not perfect in that, should more than one page be loaded simultaneously, the message may appear in the wrong one (a rare case, but a possible one), but it has worked well for me in the past.

(NOTE: These are scratched-together codes samples, trust at your own risk.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem I see with this is that if the "next" request ends up in a redirect instead of rendering a template, the message is lost, and this happens in a couple of places in the site. This is why i'm trying to clear the SESSION variable when rendering, not when the request starts

Comment: The message should only be lost, in the event of a Redirect, if the Smarty Variable is set (and the Session Variable is Unset) **before** the `header( 'Location: newpage.html' );die();` is executed. So process the redirects as far towards the top of the page as you can, and, once those hurdles are passed, then spend time setting variables for the Smarty output.